# How can I make nodeunit report previous errors?

Tags: node.js, nodeunit

I'm currently testing for the existence of a property in a response object. But if it doesn't exist the next test makes the whole thing fll on knees because test.done() never gets called.

```
foo.execute( function( error, response ) {

  test.ok( typeof response.request != 'undefined',
    "The response should have a request property" );

  test.equal( response.request.method, 'GET',
    "The request header should reflect the method used." );

  test.done();

});
```

The result is....

> FAILURES: Undone tests (or their setups/teardowns): 
>   - PostResourseGetSucceeds
>
> To fix this, make sure all tests call test.done()

How can I either make the test still report the initial test?  I've tried putting in an if statements but it just seems to cumbersome.

```
foo.execute( function( error, response ) {

  test.ok( typeof response.request != 'undefined',
    "The response should have a request property" );

  if ( typeof response.request != 'undefined' ) {
    test.equal( response.request.method, 'GET',
      "The request header should reflect the method used." );
  }

  test.done();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fell upon a simple solution, try and catch.

```
foo.execute( function( error, response ) {

  try {

    test.ok( typeof response.request != 'undefined',
      "The response should have a request property" );

    test.equal( response.request.method, 'GET',
      "The request header should reflect the method used." );

  }
  catch(e) {
    test.ok( false, "Not all tests were run." );
  };

  test.done();

});
```